# How to loop through keys and values in C using the json-c library?

Tags: c, json, json-c

I'm using json-c to parse json. Is it possible to loop through the keys and values.
json_object_object_get_ex() : this function requires prior knowledge what the keys are. What if we don't know the keys and we have to loop through them.

Comment: Take a look at https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.10/doc/html/json__object_8h.html#acf5f514a9e0061c10fc08055762639ee

Comment: @NjugunaMureithi can you please explain how does it work. What is it returning, or how can I efficiently use it. Since it is a macro I'm struggling to understand the usage

Comment: Hey man, I am not sure what you are asking me to do specifically. Can you post your code? Have you done some searches on it? Eg. This was on page 1: https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/24/json_object_object_foreach/

Comment: @NjugunaMureithi Thanks man for this article. Now I understood how to use it. Appreciate it!!

Comment: Provided an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can start at the [json_object_object_foreach](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.10/doc/html/json__object_8h.html#acf5f514a9e0061c10fc08055762639ee) macro

```
#define json_object_object_foreach(obj, key, val)
char * key;
struct json_object * val;
for (struct lh_entry * entry = json_object_get_object(obj) -> head;
  ({
    if (entry) {
      key = (char * ) entry -> k;
      val = (struct json_object * ) entry -> v;
    };entry;
  }); entry = entry -> next)
```

For usage, this [article](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/24/json_object_object_foreach/) has a good example.

```
#include <json/json.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char * string = "{"
  sitename " : "
  joys of programming ",
  "tags": ["c", "c++", "java", "PHP"],
  "author-details": {
    "name": "Joys of Programming",
    "Number of Posts": 10
  }
}
";
json_object * jobj = json_tokener_parse(string);
enum json_type type;
json_object_object_foreach(jobj, key, val) {
  printf("type: ", type);
  type = json_object_get_type(val);
  switch (type) {
  case json_type_null:
    printf("json_type_null\n");
    break;
  case json_type_boolean:
    printf("json_type_boolean\n");
    break;
  case json_type_double:
    printf("json_type_double\n");
    break;
  case json_type_int:
    printf("json_type_int\n");
    break;
  case json_type_object:
    printf("json_type_object\n");
    break;
  case json_type_array:
    printf("json_type_array\n");
    break;
  case json_type_string:
    printf("json_type_string\n");
    break;
  }
}
}
```